# MySQL + PHP order by combined string

Tags: mysql, sorting

I'm developing a voucher plugin for my girlfriends business.
the voucher-id (vid) looks like this 2016-1, first part is the current year and the second part is the current voucher id.

My problem is now to order the vids ASC / DESC.

The output now is:

```
- 2016-1 
- 2016-10
- 2016-11
- 2016-12 
- 2016-13
- 2016-2
- 2016-20
- 2016-21
- etc.
```

but it should be:

```
- 2016-1 
- 2016-2
- 2016-..
- 2016-9 
- 2016-10
- 2016-11
- 2016-..
- 2016-19
- 2016-20
- 2016-21
- 2016-..
```

I think casting is no option because of the "-".

Hope anyone can help me!

regards

M.

Comment: Are all your data in this format (`xxxx-yy`)?

Comment: Yes, i need the vid in this format because it will also printed on the voucher afterwards.

Comment: Just wondering, why do you call it a voucher _plugin_?

Comment: haha :D in the frontend users can order vouchers. and i wrote a backend plugin for my girfriend where she can manage the vouchers. so adding / deleting / edting / sending to a user and so on

Comment: Consider amending the way in which the 'vids' are stored and constructed.

Comment: Just keep `entry-date` and `current-voucher-id`. While querying the result, concat them using `concat(year(entry_date), '-', lpad('voucher-id', '3', '0'))` and do `order by year(entry-date), voucher-id`. If you want to store them, then make a trigger on insert of a new record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all your data in this format (`xxxx-yy`) then you can try the following order by clause :

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_column,'-',1)+0,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_column,'-',-1)+0
```

**Demonstration:**

```
SET @str := '2016-01';

SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str,'-',1)+0 AS firstPart,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str,'-',-1)+0 AS secondPart;
```

**Output:**

```
firstPart   secondPart
  2016          1
```

**Note:**

the first `substring_index` function grabs the text before the hyphen and the second `substring_index` function grabs the text after the hyphen.

Later adding 0 to it converts it to a number.

**More:** Alternatively you can use `CAST` function like below:

```
ORDER BY
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_column,'-',1)) AS UNSIGNED) ,
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_column,'-',-1)) AS UNSIGNED)
```

Comment: what's the difference between the two lines?

Comment: what if the ordering is xxxx-yyy ?

Comment: the first `substring_index` function grabs the text before the hyphen and the second `substring_index` function grabs the text after the hyphen. Later adding `0` to it converts it to a number.

Comment: **what if the ordering is xxxx-yyy** : it works for any number digits

Comment: here is my query!

SELECT vid FROM rr_vouchers ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(vid,'-',1) + 0, SUBSTRING_INDEX(vid,'-',-1) + 0 DESC

thx for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should do it the other way around like `voucherid - year`. Then the ordering will work.

Or, if you want to keep it the same, try something like this

```
ORDER BY
    CAST(SUBSTRING(voucher, 5) AS INT) DESC
```

where 1,5 is "2016-" so it orders by whatever is after: the voucher id.

Comment: same question as above: what if after some weeks the voucher id looks like this: 100-2016, 101-2016 ?

Comment: That is fine...if you decide to go for my first recommendation, which you seem to now be doing^^ ? (have the voucher before the year), then no need for anything else :) and if you did go for the other option, it would only break when the year is decades and decades away (10000) so you shouldn't worry too much about that :)

Comment: id on first place had no effect sry :/ nevertheless thx for your help :D

Comment: Did you make sure it was seen as type int in the query? sorry i should have mentioned that too

Comment: ahhh ok i only restructured the vids. but now i got already the solution of  1000111 working. next time i'll give your solution a try